# Parsing the lsblk output

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, linux, child-process

I am a Python beginner learning Python 3. I have written two small functions that parse the lsblk output and return Linux physical and logical disks. Here is the first function:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE


def physical_drives():
    """
    Gets all physical drive names.

    Gets all physical drive names on a Linux system,
    parsing the lsblk utility output.

    Parameters
    ----------

    Returns
    -------
    list
        A list of strings representing drive names.

    """

    command = ['lsblk -d -o name -n']
    output = run(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

    output_string = output.stdout.decode('utf-8')
    output_string = output_string.strip()

    results = output_string.split('\n')
    return results


def main():
    print(physical_drives())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The second function:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE


def partitions(disk):
    """
    Gets all partitions for a given physical disk.

    Gets all partitions present on a physical disk
    on a Linux system.
    The function parses the lsblk utility output.

    Parameters
    ----------
    disk : string
        A string containing a disk name such as 'sda'

    Returns
    -------
    list
        A list of strings representing partitions.

    """

    command = ['lsblk -o name -n -s -l']
    output = run(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

    output_string = output.stdout.decode('utf-8')
    output_string = output_string.strip()

    results = list()
    results.extend(output_string.split('\n'))
    results = [x for x in results if x != disk and disk in x]

    return results


def main():

    from disks import physical_drives

    for drive in physical_drives():

        print(drive)
        parts = partitions(drive)

        for partition in parts:
            print('\t' + partition)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The functions are in two different files in the same directory. I would appreciate a quick review on anything that is not idiomatic/pythonic code. I also have one specific question. I have coded the functions in Ninja-Ide with lint and PEP8 suggestions turned on. In both files the IDE suggests that my `print()` statements:

```
print('\t' + partition)
print(physical_drives())
```

should be written with doubled parentheses:

```
print(('\t' + partition))
print((physical_drives()))
```

For Python 3 support, I have checked the `print()` documentation, but have been unable to find a reference for including function calls and string concatenation in double parentheses when calling `print()`.

Comment: The double-parentheses suggestion makes no sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### lsblk

The `-s` option to `lsblk` was introduced to util-linux rather recently, [in release 2.22](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.22/v2.22-ReleaseNotes).  You may experience compatibility issues on slightly older GNU/Linux installations.

But I don't see why you would want the `-s` option at all — it just gives you an inverted device tree.  For example, on my machine:

> ```
> $ lsblk -o name -n -s -l
> sda1
> sda
> sda2
> sda
> sr0
> vg-root
> sda3
> sda
> vg-var
> sda3
> sda
> vg-data
> sda3
> sda
> ```

In the output, `sda` appears multiple times.  To understand the output, you need to drop the `-l` flag so that the list appears in tree form:

> ```
> $ lsblk -o name -n -s
> sda1
> └─sda
> sda2
> └─sda
> sr0
> vg-root
> └─sda3
>   └─sda
> vg-var
> └─sda3
>   └─sda
> vg-data
> └─sda3
>   └─sda
> ```

Now, it's more apparent that the `-s` option isn't helpful.  If you drop it, then the output makes more sense:

> ```
> $ lsblk -o name -n
> sda
> ├─sda1
> ├─sda2
> └─sda3
>   ├─vg-root
>   ├─vg-var
>   └─vg-data
> sr0
> $ lsblk -o name -n -l
> sda
> sda1
> sda2
> sda3
> vg-root
> vg-var
> vg-data
> sr0
> ```

To list the devices on `sda`, it would be better to run `lsblk -o name -n -l /dev/sda` — that would immediately drop `sr0` from consideration, for example.  Note that LVM volumes (such as `vg-root` above) would still appear in the output.  I don't think that doing a substring search (`if x != disk and disk in x` in your code) is a reliable filter.  It could be fooled if there are [more than 26 physical disks](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/o9b3e/for_those_of_you_who_were_curious_this_is_what/c3ff7n5/): the 27th disk would be named `sdaa`.  It might also be fooled by exceptionally tricky naming of LVM volumes.

### Subprocess execution

Whenever practical, I recommend avoiding the shell when executing subprocesses.  The shell introduces a set of potential security vulnerabilities — for example, shenanigans with the `PATH` environment variable.  Best practice would be to run the command with a specific executable and pre-parsed command-line options:

```
run('/bin/lsblk -o name -n -s -l'.split(), stdout=PIPE)
```

### Alternative solution

I actually wouldn't bother with parsing the output of `lsblk` at all.  After all, `lsblk` is just a way to report the contents of the sysfs filesystem.  You would be better off inspecting `/sys` directly.

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import basename, dirname

def physical_drives():
    drive_glob = '/sys/block/*/device'
    return [basename(dirname(d)) for d in glob(drive_glob)]

def partitions(disk):
    if disk.startswith('.') or '/' in disk:
        raise ValueError('Invalid disk name {0}'.format(disk))
    partition_glob = '/sys/block/{0}/*/start'.format(disk)
    return [basename(dirname(p)) for p in glob(partition_glob)]
```

Comment: I used the -s option because the output seemed easier to parse. I will definitelly check out your alternative solution. I didn't like using text parsing for my functions either, i was hoping for something like an API call but was unable to find one. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This code looks okay, but I would simplify a few things:

This:

```
output_string = output.stdout.decode('utf-8')
output_string = output_string.strip()

results = output_string.split('\n')
return results
```

could be :

```
return output.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip().split('\n')
```

this:

```
def main():
    print(physical_drives())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

could be:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(physical_drives())
```

this:

```
output_string = output.stdout.decode('utf-8')
output_string = output_string.strip()

results = list()
results.extend(output_string.split('\n'))
results = [x for x in results if x != disk and disk in x]
return results
```

could be:

```
results = output.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip().split('\n'))
return [x for x in results if x != disk and disk in x]
```

this:

```
parts = partitions(drive)

for partition in parts:
    print('\t' + partition)
```

could be:

```
for partition in partitions(drive):
    print('\t' + partition)
```

And finally, I see no reason for the double paren to the print function.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestions. I am sorry I can mark only one post as the answer.

Comment: @Anonimista No worries. The concept that a single code review is `the` answer is just odd.  Hopefully code reviews are additive and they are all useful is some way.  :-)

Comment: Especially because the answers complement one another. Your answer suggests how to write more pythonic code and the other answer is related to my use of lsblk. Oh, well.

Answer (score 2):

The logic can be moved out to an external process, if you're able to install **jq** (command-line JSON parsing tool).

Command: `apt install jq`

Then the code can be reduced to just:

```
import os
resp = os.popen('lsblk -J  | jq -c .').readline().strip()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: @TobySpeight I disagree. I think that processing JSON is clearly simpler and better, and passes the ["Oh, duh!" test](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7018/9357).

Comment: @200 I've added an introductory sentence or two to make this a review.  HTH.